# How to iterate over tags in a latex file?

Tags: tables, parsing

I am working on a problem where I have been given a file and I have to find all the cells in all the tables in the latex document(Basically I have to make a border for all the cells. Currently, I am iterating through the latex file and then changing the code inside the latex file using regular expression in order to change the latex code so that I can get an output like [https://imgur.com/undefined] from [https://imgur.com/a/aUNaInv]. One of my friend who is working on the same problem but he is using docx files instead of latex. I got to know that we can iterate through the tags and can even change them in latex. Is there a similar approach to latex also. My friend's code for docx is as follows

```
for chl in root:
    for chl1 in chl:
        for chl2 in chl1:
            if chl2.tag =='{urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0}table-cell-properties':
                chl2.set('{urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0}background-color', '#000000')
                chl2.set('{urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0}border', '1pt solid #ffffff')
                chl2.set('{urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0}border-top', '1pt solid #ffffff')
                chl2.set('{urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0}border-bottom', '1pt solid #ffffff')
                chl2.set('{urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0}border-left', '1pt solid #ffffff')
                chl2.set('{urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0}border-right', '1pt solid #ffffff')
```

Comment: latex is not an xml-file like docx, so normally you can't use such commands.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is there an easier way than the regular expression to parse through tags in latex?

Comment: note that latex never holds the document in memory so the mechanisms are entirely different. Normally you can redefine the markup to do whatever you need rather than editing the file, please load the images on to this site not use external links so we can see what layout you need.